# Physical meaning for Schrödinger equation on a periodic domain with a certain condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

We study the Schrödinger equation in a periodic domain

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    i\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0  \qquad                        & x \in [0, \ell(t)] \\
    u(0, t) = 0,  u(\ell(t), t) = 0 \qquad        & t \ge 0\\
    u(x,0) = u_0              \qquad                       & x \in [0,1]\\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

Here, $t \in [0,T]$, $\ell(t) = 1+\varepsilon \sin(\omega t)$ where $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and $\omega \in (0,\frac{4}{\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon)})$.

Due to my research, after some transformation, we need the following condition:

\begin{equation}
\sup_{t \in [0,T]}|\ell(t )u_x(\ell(t),t)|^2 \leq c_T^2 < \frac{1-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}\int_{0}^{1}|u_x(x,0)|^2 dx
\end{equation}

where $c_T$ is some constant depending on $T$.

Can anyone help me to explain the physical meaning behind this formula. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order it is significant for more people.

Comment: Are you interested in the physical meaning of the constraint $\sup_{t}|\ell(t)u_x(\ell(t),t)| \cdots$? or the physical meaning of the problem? both?

Comment: I am interested to know the meaning of the left hand side